# If a textbox value (text) equals nothing, does that count as $false?

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering if a "TextBox" .text value = empty, is that the same as "$false?"
I have a form, with a simple "TextBox" :

```
$TextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox.Name = 'TextBox'
$TextBox.Width = 175
$TextBox.Height = 100
$TextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,170)
$TextBox.AutoSize = $true
$TextBox.add_MouseHover($ShowHelp)
```

Now, that textbox doesn't have a set .Text value, so what I'm wondering is if the .Text = nothing or hasn't been entered yet, would that count as "$false"

Comment: Try `[bool]$textbox.text`. If you ***never set*** it, it should be `$False`. The default value is empty string.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Great - That's what I wanted to know :) thanks a bunch!

Comment: For clarification purposes, `$false` and empty string are not the same because they are different types. However, when doing a boolean comparison, PowerShell will be coerced into evaluating empty string as `False`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings you should add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a default instance of `[System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]`, the `Text` property value defaults to empty string. `$false` and empty string are not the same because they are different types, Boolean and String, respectively. When performing a boolean comparison, PowerShell will be coerced into evaluating empty string as `False`. You can also just cast the empty string as a Boolean. You can see this behavior below:

```
$box = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]::new()

# .Text Type Check
$box.Text.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

# Empty String Length 0
$box.Text.Length
0

# Casting to Boolean
[bool]$box.Text
False

# Testing with Boolean Conditional Statement
if ($box.Text) { "it is true" } else { "it is false"}
it is false
```